# SSRS group on lookup field

Tags: reporting-services, dataset, grouping, lookup

I have an ssrs matrix and have a lookup to another dataset2 field (Jurisdiction)

I want to row group by this dataset2 Jurisdiction.

The problem is that the tablix will work on a non group lookup but will not allow me to group on  and display the dataset jurisdiction field.

is this possible in ssrs?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried this ? - https://github.com/OzLocke/SSRSAggLookup

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule, it's much better to join subqueries in the SQL rather than using the `Lookup` function. Both in terms of efficiency and also avoiding the limitation you described in the report design.

If the datasets are truly different data sources, consider using an ETL process to combine them into a single table for the report to use as its dataset.